# Looping over read in bash until correct input is given

Tags: linux, bash

What would be the proper way to pass command as variable into prompt? For example, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=`ifconfig tap0 | awk '{print $2}' | egrep "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"`

read -p "Enter your IP: " prompt
        if [[ $prompt == i ]]
    then
        echo "Correct IP, congrats"
    else 
read -p "Wrong IP, try again: " prompt
        if [[ $prompt == i ]]
    then
        echo "Correct IP, congrats"
    else
        echo "Wrong IP for the second time, exiting."
    exit 0
fi
```

I am sure this can be looped, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply put your condition in a `while` loop, i.e. as long as your condition isn't satisfied, `read` from `stdin` and ask for proper input.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
i=$(ifconfig tap0 | awk '{print $2}' | egrep "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}")
read -p "Enter IP address: " prompt
while [ "$i" != "$prompt" ] ; do
  echo "Wrong IP address"
  read -p "Enter IP address: " prompt
done
echo "Correct IP, congrats"
```

If you want to abort after a maximum amount of wrong inputs, add a counter

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_TRIES="5"

clear
i="$(ifconfig tap0 | awk '{print $2}' | egrep "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}")"
t="0"
read -p "Enter IP address: " prompt
while [ "$i" != "$prompt" -a "$t" -lt "$MAX_TRIES" ] ; do
  echo "Wrong IP address"
  t="$((t+1))"
  read -p "Enter IP address: " prompt
done

if [ "$t" -eq "$MAX_TRIES" ] ; then
  echo "Too many wrong inputs"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Correct IP, congrats"
exit 0
```

Comment: Slight modifications to check for MAX_TRIES:

#!/bin/bash

MAX_TRIES="5"

clear
i="$(ifconfig tap0 | awk '{print $2}' | egrep "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}")"
t="0"
read -p "Enter IP address: " prompt
while [ "$i" != "$prompt" -a "$t" -lt "$MAX_TRIES" ] ; do
  echo "Wrong IP address"
  t="$((t+1))"
  read -p "Enter IP address: " prompt

  if [ "$t" -eq "$MAX_TRIES" ] ; then
      echo "Too many wrong inputs"
      exit 1
  fi

done


echo "Correct IP, congrats"
exit 0